# Building using single sided PCB proto-board

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-assembly

I have a prototype board like this one:
[image: here]

**Note that mine does not have the arrows/numbers on the side. Looks like a cutout from the middle section.**

It only has golden circles on top. So far I'm used to using a prototype breadboard like this one:

[image: here]

I have an Particle Photon board. I assume i put it's pins from the other side but how do I than wire from there. For instance I have few other controllers which should all ground to the Particle Photon GND. How do I wire them to my GND pin ?

Comment: Wire-wrap to the rescue!  ...or far less cool, but way more piratical (practical), solder point-to-point using wires.  1950 tech?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_wrap

Comment: What I do is run a bare wire in a line and solder everything to that.

Comment: See my answer to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/395058/73158 for benefits of using strip board instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here my work
[image]

1. For short distance, use point to point soldering (use resister lead as base)
2. For long connect use wire soldering
3. for jumper you can use 0 Ohm resister
4. For other module use male or female pin header